# Windows service installation assigning to the created user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, installation, remoting

Whenever a windows service is installed/reinstalled, i want to assign the set user  to the service ie. if the service is running under a user test123 with a password,i need  to make sure when the installer is ran the service is attached to the same user (not to any localsystem (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem)).

---

```
    //Check whether my service exists- MyWinService is my service name.

     System.Management.SelectQuery sQuery = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format("select Name,startname from Win32_Service where name ='MyWinService' ")); 
 using (System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtSearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery))
{
                        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject service1 in mgmtSearcher.Get())
            {
string servicelogondetails =
string.Format("Name: {0} ,  Logon : {1} ", service1["Name"].ToString(), service1["startname"]).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(servicelogondetails).ToString();
              }
 }
```

---

I am not able to find passsword property to assign it (I don't want to view/read, just assign back).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller installer=new
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller(); 

installer.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
```

My question is if i assign to ServiceAccount.User, do i need to set again user name & password or if its ServiceAccount.User will take care of user name and password?
If i need to assign password back to installer, how do i can do that? Thanks in advance.

```
installer.Password = <<something>>;
installer.Username = <<something>>;
```

PS: System.Management.dll is referenced to the project & using System.Management is being added to the namespace in order for System.Management.SelectQuery to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning UserName, Password to Installer is optional. If not passed, it will be prompted when installing the service.

If you want to assign userName & password, you can do so by reading from some external configuration file and assign them.

I'm not aware that there is a way you can retrieve user credential from existing service and assign them.

Comment: I am able to get user name via  service1["Name"].ToString() from the above code, all i am trying is to get & assign password, so that i can avoid that pop up that comes while installing.

Comment: Sorry its from service1["startname"].ToString(); //For user name